# How to destroy line graph in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I got a graph that updates when I select start and end date from my JSON data. But the old graph still appears when I hover over the points.

I have read a lot of post about using `myLineChart.destroy();`but I'm unable to find a means to add  to my [graph](https://jsfiddle.net/ekom89/6oa1vsf9/).

```js
var cdata = [{
    "_id": "585b544f5c86b6c8537c34d6",
    "topic": "Humidity",
    "message": 30,
    "message1": 2,
    "when": "2016-12-22T04:19:27.000Z"
}, {
    "_id": "585b54505c86b6c8537c34d7",
    "topic": "Humidity",
    "message": 10,
    "message1": 25,
    "when": "2016-12-22T04:19:28.000Z"
}, {
    "_id": "585b54515c86b6c8537c34d8",
    "topic": "Humidity",
    "message": 20,
    "message1": 30,
    "when": "2016-12-22T04:19:29.000Z"
}, {
    "_id": "585b54525c86b6c8537c34d9",
    "topic": "Humidity",
    "message": 50,"message1": 40,
    "when": "2016-12-22T04:19:30.000Z"
}, {
    "_id": "585b54535c86b6c8537c34da",
    "topic": "Humidity",
    "message": 45,
    "message1": 21,
    "when": "2016-12-22T04:19:31.000Z"
}]
var labeldata = [];
var chrtdata = [];
var chartdata = [];

for(var i =0; i < cdata.length; i++)
{
  labeldata.push(cdata[i].when);
  chrtdata.push(cdata[i].message)
  chartdata.push(cdata[i].message1)
}


var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labeldata,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Humidity',
      data: chrtdata,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 51, 0,0.6)"
    },
    {
      label: 'Temperature',
      data: chartdata,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(102, 0, 255,0.6)"
    },
    
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me out with this.

Comment: What happens when you keep `if(myChart) {myChart.update();}` at the top your code?

Comment: @DavidR what part of my graph?

Comment: Just before your `var cdata` declaration.

Comment: @DavidR Thanks for your response.

Comment: @DavidR That didnt work for me. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Can you please post your complete code, through which we can check the data update?

Comment: You need to make it function based as you changes your dates that function will reinitialize your graph by destroying the existing graph first using `myLineChart.destroy()`

Comment: @DavidR Kindly see AshishPanchal [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ashishpce2007/6oa1vsf9/3/) my graph has a similar function. Unfortunately his JSfiddle doesn't provide a suitable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/6oa1vsf9/5/) is the example you can change your graph with dynamic values without destroying it. Hope it helps.

```js
function getRandomJson() {
    var cdata = [{
        "_id": "585b544f5c86b6c8537c34d6",
        "topic": "Humidity",
        "message": Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 20 + 1)) + 20,
        "message1": Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 5 + 1)) + 5,
        "when": "2016-12-22T04:19:27.000Z"
    }, {
        "_id": "585b54505c86b6c8537c34d7",
        "topic": "Humidity",
        "message": Math.floor(Math.random() * (80 - 1 + 1)) + 1,
        "message1": Math.floor(Math.random() * (40 - 5 + 1)) + 5,
        "when": "2016-12-22T04:19:28.000Z"
    }, {
        "_id": "585b54515c86b6c8537c34d8",
        "topic": "Humidity",
        "message": Math.floor(Math.random() * (90 - 20 + 1)) + 20,
        "message1": Math.floor(Math.random() * (60 - 20 + 1)) + 20,
        "when": "2016-12-22T04:19:29.000Z"
    }, {
        "_id": "585b54525c86b6c8537c34d9",
        "topic": "Humidity",
        "message": Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 40 + 1)) + 40,
        "message1": Math.floor(Math.random() * (70 - 30 + 1)) + 30,
        "when": "2016-12-22T04:19:30.000Z"
    }, {
        "_id": "585b54535c86b6c8537c34da",
        "topic": "Humidity",
        "message": Math.floor(Math.random() * (85 - 20 + 1)) + 20,
        "message1": Math.floor(Math.random() * (65 - 35 + 1)) + 35,
        "when": "2016-12-22T04:19:31.000Z"
    }];
    return cdata;
}

loadGraph();
function loadGraph() {
var labeldata = [];
var chrtdata = [];
var chartdata = [];
var cdata = getRandomJson();
for(var i =0; i < cdata.length; i++)
{
  labeldata.push(cdata[i].when);
  chrtdata.push(cdata[i].message)
  chartdata.push(cdata[i].message1)
}
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labeldata,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Humidity',
      data: chrtdata,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 51, 0,0.6)"
    },
    {
      label: 'Temperature',
      data: chartdata,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(102, 0, 255,0.6)"
    },
    ]
  }
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.2/Chart.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" onClick="loadGraph()">Change Me!</button>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just checked out your Jsfiddle solution. Apparently after clicking the button several times it loads the previous graphs like my problem. My graph is similar to your solution which is function based. Kindly check.

Comment: @Ekom : I have loaded **JSON** with random data so whenever you click button It will load data randomly based on the ranges I have given what you have to do is getting **JSON** based on your search result and you will be able to load that data into graph. Hope you get my point Or let me know if you have any further queries.

Comment: When  I click the button several times say 5 times it doesn't destroy the previous graph. The first 3 times it's okay. Try it a couple of times to see what I mean.

Comment: @Ekom : There wasn't any issue of graph destroy. Its just that we have to declare the array variables inside the loadGraph function. see my updated answer and fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6oa1vsf9/5/ Hope it helps you and now you got what you want. Thanks.